# Ninject Interceptor calling twice beforeinvoke and afterinvoke methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, ninject-extensions, ninject-interception

I am developing an app in asp.net in which I am implementing the Ninject Interceptor in which I am binding/registering the service like

```
kernel.Bind<IPracticeManagement>().To<PracticeManagementClient>().InRequestScope().Intercept().With<TimingInterceptor>();
```

When I am calling the method of this service

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPracticeManagement _practiceManagement;

        public HomeController(IPracticeManagement practiceManagement)
        {
            this._practiceManagement = practiceManagement;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var specialities = this._practiceManagement.GetSpecialty();

            this.ViewBag.Specialities = specialities;

            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }
}
```

The method BeforeInvoke is calling twice in TimeInterceptor. Why?

Comment: Have you put a break point in `GetSpecialty` is it called once or twice? Also how is your `TimingInterceptor` implementation look like?

Comment: GetSpecialty is calling once.

Comment: Then you should put a breakpoint in BeforeIncoke and check `invocation` maybe it request the `GetSpecialty` and a different method for the second time...

Comment: I want to know which attribute of invocation has relevant information. There are alot of attributes in the invocation.

Comment: For start you should look the at the `invocation.Request.Method` to get which method is currently intercepted. Then the `invocation.Request.Context.Request.ParentRequest.Service` to check whether it both times your controller.

Comment: Both times invocation.Request.Method and invocation.Request.Context.Request.ParentRequest.Service are same. :(

Comment: Hey there - did you find a solution for this problem? I'm encountering it too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have both of `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.DynamicProxy` and `Ninject.Extensions.Interception.Linfu` installed? If it so, then try to use only one of it.